# Position Icons on Top Right removing them from flow

Tags: css

I created a DIV which on the right top corner must have two links (Menu and Options):

```
<div class="Clear">
    <ul class="Clear">
      <li><a>Menu</a></li>
      <li><a>Options</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

To align the ul on the right I used "float: right".

The online example is in: http://jsfiddle.net/y2hhm/8/

Each link text will be replace by an icon image using background-image.

It looks fine on the first DIV. But on the second the table is pushed down.

I also tried "position:absolute" but it makes hard to align it on the right.

Does anyone knows how to make the Menu/Options list look the same in both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Tables have default styles applied to them by the browser. To solve this specific problem on your second fiddle (yellow-orange one), you need to **set the table's `border-spacing: 0;`**.

Perhaps you can turn to CSS resets if these pre-set properties annoy you.

**-----------------------------**

I think you might have overlooked the fact that ul's and ol's have a default styling applied to them, which differs from browser to browser. Some might set padding, others margin (I haven't tested it myself).

All you need to do is add this to your CSS: (tested and working in your fiddle)

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Your h2 element and table element respond differently to the float of the ul. If you set your h2 CSS to `clear:both` the margin from the ul will also impact it. The table element for some reason considers the margin of your floated element (I can't explain why).

**NB: // are not valid CSS comments. Use /* */.**

If you absolutely want the menu to be removed from the flow, set the parent div to `position: relative;` and the ul to `position: absolute; margin-left: 80%; margin-top: 0%;`.

The disadvantage of this method is that you have to approximately estimate the menu's length. (in this case I took 80% margin, so estimated at 20%) . Given that your divs have dynamic widths, it will also cause the menu to float outside of the table when the viewport is too small. You can prevent this by setting the div to `overflow: hidden;`, but overall...

If this were a problem I had to solve, I would simply stick with the `float: right;` and leave some whitespace between the menu and the next elements...

Comment: I edited and improved my example. What I am looking for is the UL to be over the yellow areas without pushing the div and table down. Does it make sense? I have been trying Floats and Absolute Positioning but no luck ...

Comment: I'm sorry I had a second look at your fiddle and there are no yellow areas? Could you repost a working link? But honestly if you follow the instructions in my answer, it will work. Guaranteed, I tested it. What part is causing a problem?

Comment: This is what I am looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/y2hhm/14/. I still have a different space between the orange UL and the Green line in the H2 and TABLE examples. But probably this is not possible to solve. In this example I am using "position:absolute". It was the only way I was able to make it work. Can you post an example in jsFiddle of how are you doing it? Thank You,